# CMake add dependencies to internal library in a cousin directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following project structure:

```
│   CMakeLists.txt
├───lib
│   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   ├───lib_a
│   │       CMakeLists.txt
│   ├───lib_b
│   │       CMakeLists.txt
│   └───lib_c
│           CMakeLists.txt
└───src
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    └───app
        ├───controller
        |        CMakeLists.txt
        └───endorser
                 CMakeLists.txt
```

The libraries are located in `lib` directory. `lib_b` links against `lib_a` and `lib_c` links against `lib_b`. CMake recognizes targets between libraries with no problem. For example having these lines in `lib/lib_c/CMakeLists.txt` file works perfectly fine:

```
target_link_libraries(lib_c lib_a lib_b)
```

However trying to do the same in the `src/app/controller` fails with following error:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at src/app/controller/CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
[cmake]   By not providing "Findlib_c.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
[cmake]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "lib_c", but
[cmake]   CMake did not find one.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "lib_c" with any of
[cmake]   the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     lib_cConfig.cmake
[cmake]     lib_c-config.cmake
```

And this is how I search for `lib_c`:

```
# Check for dependencies
find_package(lib_c REQUIRED)
...
# link against it
target_link_libraries(controller lib_c)
```

How can I export `lib_c` **without having to install it**, in such a way that `src/app` can link against?

Anyway, CMakeLists.txt of non-leaf directories contain only `add_subdirectory` calls:

```
# lib/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
add_subdirectory(lib_a)
add_subdirectory(lib_b)
add_subdirectory(lib_c)
```

Comment: "However trying to do the same in the `src/app` fails." - What do you mean by "**fails**"? Do you got any error message? Or what? Please, add more details about that problem.

Comment: CMake complaints that it can not find `lib_c` and I should provide a `find-lib_c.cmake` or similar

Comment: @Tsyvarev I just added more details

Comment: So, the script `src/app/controller/CMakeLists.txt` is written expecting `lib_c` library to be **external** to the application project. Now you want to build both application and libraries in the **same project**, which would contradict expectation of the application's `CMakeLists.txt`. You ask us how to "fake" (emulate) these expectations, so the application could be built succesfully without changing its `CMakeLists.txt`. Am I correctly understand your problem?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes exactly. The same approach (`find_package` then `target_link_libraries`)  works with libraries in sibling directories. I would like to have it the same way for other directories as well.

Comment: Em, so do your `src/lib/lib_c/CMakeLists.txt` script also contains `find_package(lib_b)` which works? In that case you definitely have either `Findlib_b.cmake` or `lib_bConfig.cmake`. Or do libraries (under `src/lib`) **not** use `find_package()` to detect each other? This would mean that the libraries expect to be built together, in the same project (e.g. with `src/lib/CMakeLists.txt`). So I don't sure why you compare "**internal**" linking of these libraries together with "**external**" linking of application with that libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes it does. and yes it works. I do not have `Findlib_b.cmake` nor `lib_bConfig.cmake` and I have not exported them. Libraries under `src/lib` **do** use `find_package()` to find each other.

Comment: It is impossible to have `find_package()` work without "Find" or "Config" script. May be, your libraries' `CMakeLists.txt` execute `find_package` **conditionally**? Or they execute `find_package` without REQUIRED option (and, possibly, with QUITE option), so `find_package` failing doesn't prevent `CMakeLists.txt` to continue. If `find_package` is executed, CMake configuration log (output of `cmake`) has always a line(s) describing its result. Please, show these lines when you configure your library project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev let me write a minimal test...

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are right! I was mistaken, There is no `find_package` call for internal libraries. Just linking against them directly works fine!

Comment: So, is the problem stated in the question post resolved (or is it not a problem at all)? If the problem remains, please update the question post and incorporate information from the comments into it.